# async await and threading

Tags: c#, async-await

based on what I have read on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be
>   created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async
>   method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current
>   synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the
>   method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a
>   background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process
>   that's just waiting for results to become available.

It is basically saying no thread will be created. But inside a class which I inherited `HttpClient` I found something interesting..

```
async Task<T> SendAsync<T>(HttpMethod method, Uri uri, HttpContent content, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
        HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri); 
        msg.Content = content;
        //On Main Thread
        HttpResponseMessage response = await SendAsync(msg, cancellationToken);
        //On worker thread
        //...
}
```

the method is called inside `static void Main`

```
Task result = client.GetAsync<string>(...);
//GetAsync calls await SendAsync<T>
result.Wait();
```

Why am I on a separate thread after `await SendAsnc` call?? I thought asyn creats no new thread. Or at least it will be invoked back to the original thread after await.

Comment: If you don't *have* a synchronization context, then the continuation from an async method will run on a threadpool thread. Console applications (which I'm assuming this is, as you reference `Main()`) do not have a synchronization context by default.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is poorly advertised in the documentation, but the way that async/await works in a console application is very different than how it works in a UI application due to the lack of a synchronization context in a console application. [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) describes details and gives a code sample of how add one so that async/await behaves in a more predictable way.

Normally, you're absolutely correct about async/await not *necessarily* entailing multithreading (although things like Task.Run *do*, in fact, cause the code in question to run in the thread pool), but (as described in the article I linked to) in a console application async/await could run anywhere.

My usual analogy for how async works when running on the same thread is to think of going to a restaurant with 9 other people (so 10 people total). When the waiter comes by, 9 of the people are ready and the 10th isn't. In this case, the waiter will take the other 9 people's orders first and then come back to the 10th person. If for whatever reason the 10th person's being *really* slow the waiter could always bring the orders back to the kitchen and come back when the 10th person's ready.

Clearly, there's no point to bringing in a second waiter just to wait for the 10th guy to be ready to order, and it would clearly be inefficient to make everyone else wait for the one guy to be ready. Adding extra waiters to the situation won't speed things up because the delay isn't being caused by a lack of waiters, it's caused by the 10th guy being slow to make up his mind (and there's nothing the wait staff can do about that).

Answer (score 11):

I describe this behavior in my [introduction to `async` blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

In summary, this is correct:

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created.

And so is this:

> I thought asyn creats no new thread.

This is *not* correct:

> Or at least it will be invoked back to the original thread after await.

`async` and `await` - *by themselves* - do not cause any additional threads to be created. However, after an `await` completes, the remainder of the `async` method must run *somewhere*.

By default, `await` captures a "context", which is the current `SynchronizationContext` (unless it is `null`, in which case the current context is the current `TaskScheduler`). UI threads have their own synchronization context (e.g., `WinFormsSynchronizationContext` or `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`), and in that case, the `async` method will continue executing on that same UI thread.

In a Console application, there is no synchronization context, so the "context" captured by `await` will be the thread pool context. Thus, when the `async` method is ready to resume, it will be scheduled to the thread pool and picked up by some thread there.

Answer (score 1):

Console Applications have a thread pool SynchronizationContext instead of a one-chunk-at-a-time SynchronizationContext that is used in GUI and ASP.Net Applications, so when the await completes, it schedules the remainder of the async method on a thread pool thread.
read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more information about async await behavior.