# Why is my async method giving me error

Tags: c#

```
    public static async Task<decimal> Add(string input1, string input2)
    {
        decimal number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(input1);
        decimal number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(input2);

        decimal sum = 0M;
        sum = await Add(number1, number2); //PROBLEM HERE

        return sum;
    }

    public static decimal Add(decimal number1, decimal number2)
    {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
}
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'
>   and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'decimal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Note: Sorry for the trival-ness of the example

Comment: Because you cannot `await` a method that is not mark as `async`

Comment: @Bidou Actually it's not because the method is not `async`, but because the method does not return an awaitable type like `Task`.

Comment: The fact that you believe this code is meaningful indicates to me that you possibly don't understand what await does. Can you explain what you believe await does?

Answer (score 3):

As others have indicated, you can't await the `Add` method because it doesn't return a `Task`.

```
public static Task<decimal> Add(decimal number1, decimal number2)
{
    // Async code goes here
    return number1 + number2;
}
```

I'd also like to point out, though, that if all you're doing in the `Add` method is `return number1 + number2;` then it's pointless at best to use `await` here in the first place. Addition is not an expensive operation, so you'll actually *decrease* your performance by doing it on a background thread (because of the overhead associated with the thread and async/await).

Also, as @juharr indicated, the primary use case of async/await is IO-bound operations, which this is not. There are two ways you can use async/await:

- Perform some operation in the thread pool - this is used for CPU-bound tasks. In this regard, in one sense at least the Task Parallel library didn't add a fundamentally "new" functionality (the Thread Pool obviously already existed), it just made it more convenient to use.
- The primary application of async/await is doing asynchronous operations on the same thread. This is used for IO-bound tasks. The idea here is that if all you're doing is waiting for a result from some result (e.g. a file download) there's no reason the calling thread can't do other work in the meantime. While you could do event-driven asynchronous programming in some cases previously, the Task Parallel Library makes this dramatically more convenient.

While what you have is *technically* a CPU-bound operation, the way you're using it right now is pointless because it won't improve performance at all - not even a little bit. Addition is very fast as it can easily be implemented in hardware (and most modern processors do), and you're not doing any true parallelism here in any case (i.e. you're just waiting for the result anyway, so it's not like you're doing any other work in the interim while the addition's being computed).

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249169/async-await-and-threading/40249260) has some additional details (plus anything by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary), who's one of the best writers on the topic in my opinion).

Comment: It's not about how expensive the operation is, but the fact that it is a CPU bound operation instead of IO (which is the main point of asynchronous code).

Comment: @juharr Fair point, I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Point taken....