# async and await code behaving differently if we run it from different processes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, console-application, filesystemwatcher

Please bear with me for this long question.

Scenario:
I have a `FileSystemWatcher` on the *root-directory* which is watching for `LastWrite` change on *control-file* each inside a *control-directory*. Looks something like this:-

> *root-directory* (`FileSystemWatcher` instance is watching this root directory)
>
> |
>
> |-----*control-directory_0* \ control-file
>
> ```
>                       \ data-file
> ```
>
> |-----*control-directory_1* \ control-file
>
> ```
>                       \ data-file
> ```
>
> |-----*control-directory_2* \ control-file
>
> ```
>                       \ data-file
> ```
>
> |-----*control-directory_3* \ control-file
>
> ```
>                       \ data-file
> ```
>
> .........more similar structure (but only one *root-directory*)

Sorry for my creative drawing.

The problem I was facing, there can be many *control-directories* inside the *root-directory* (approx 200-500) and along with *control-directory's* *control-file*, I have a *data-file* in it (in each of them) where continuous writes are happening.

I was watching for `NotifyFilter.LastWrite` and `Filter = control-file`.
`InternalBufferSize` is set to 4KB (please don't ask to increase this, I am not allowed to modify it and event to make it 8KB (default one) due to requirements and I can't use `FileSystemWatcher` for each *control-file* as it will take lot of precious non-paged memory).

My `EventHandler` looks like this

```
  private void OnChange(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
     //result = CPU bound work here
     //evaluating result
  }
```

Currently, I am handling 300 *control-files*. Due to lots of writes happening on *data-file* and lots of requests coming to *control-file* my buffer is overflowing quite regularly.

Then I thought of an idea. (`async` and `await` to the rescue with `Task` battle tank)

```
  async private void OnChange(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
     var result = await Task.Run(() => Work.CPUboundWork());
     //evaluating result
  }
```

It was working fine and I was able to handle lots of requests (even tested with 1000 events with only 4KB buffer).

Now comes the interesting part. How am I testing it?

There are two entities involved, one, writing to the *control* or *data-file* and second, handling the events generated by the writes to the *control-file*. So I went up and created a console app, which does both of the things.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int controlFileCount = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
  string basePath = args[1];
  //CreateFolderStructure(basePath, controlFileCount); for first run.
  FileSystemWatcher baseDirectoryWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  SetupFileSystemWatcher(baseDirectoryWatcher, basePath);
  WriteToControlFilesParallely(basePath, controlFileCount);
  Console.Read();
}

public void SetupFileSystemWatcher(FileSystemWatcher baseDirectoryWatcher, string path)
{
  //setting properties of the watcher.
  baseDirectoryWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilter.LastWrite;
  baseDirectoryWatcher.Filter = "control-file";
  baseDirectoryWatcher.InternalBufferSize = 4096;
  baseDirectoryWatcher.Path = path;
  baseDirectoryWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
  baseDirectoryWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

public void WriteToControlFilesParallely(string basePath, int controlFileCount)
{
  Parallel.For(0, controlFileCount, (i) =>
  {
    string filePath = Helper.GetFilePath(basePath, i);
    Helper.WriteData(filePath, "data");
  });
}
```

Next, I tested with two console applications:-

First, Responsible of writing data to various control files parallelly - (*Writer_App*).

Second, Responsible for handling events - (*Event_Handling_App*).

NOTE: There's no code change in the core but instead of writing and handling the events in the same console app now I am writing from one and handling form other.

So I separated the two *entities* from my old console app (starting a simulation to the actual environment). Now I started testing by running first *Event_Handling_App* and then write to the *control-file* by running *Writer_App* and now the things have become strange and my application is facing `InternalBufferOverflow` exception for the same number of *control-files* and same number of writes when I didn't have the `async` and `await` as in my first implementation.

I again tested with one console app (which is having both the responsibilities) and it was working fine.

> So, why two console applications make the magic of `async` and `await` (along with `Task`) disappear while one console application is working great?
>
> Is it something related to Inter Process Communication?
>
> I am wondering if it will work in production because I will be using handler code in a Web application and some other process can write these files over the network.

Comment: Does the console application that works set up a Form at some point? `async/await` relies on a `SynchronizationContext` that handles synchronization. Is there a proper one in a bare-bones console application?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen there's nothing like that its simple console app. No "UI Context" involved.

Comment: Please check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40249260/4032703) - the way async/await works in a console application is very different than how it works in, for example, a UI application.

Comment: @EJoshuaS But the thing is why it worked in case of one console app and not in case of two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to figure out this, when I was using single console app I was running its exe (through cmd) but when I was trying with two console app I was running the app inside visual studio (in release mode) so due to this (with load of visual studio) I was getting the exception and I was blaming `async` and `await`.

So, Always run your application from exe if you are dealing with code which is tight.